# Number, each of it stored in 1 array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was trying to code something in which 
It takes each number inside a number and put each number in array..

For example :

number (equals to) `21135`
Array_number (equals to) `[2,1,1,3,5]`

Or get each number alone

number (equals to) `2261`

```
N1 (equals to) 2
N2 (equals to) 2
N3 (equals to) 6
N4 (equals to) 1
```

I was thinking to  convert it to a `str` and find but it will be in unarranged order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `map(int, str())`

```
>>>array_num = map(int, str(21135))
[2, 1, 1, 3, 5]
>>>int(''.join(map(str,array_num)))
21135 #will bring it back into normal
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go :)

```
number = 21135
Array_number = [int(n) for n in str(number)]
```

Comment: I want to say thanks but they will flag the comment .. Lol .. Do you know how to put them back  again ?

Comment: Use `int("".join(Array_number))`.

Comment: Says: Value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : 'c_number'

Comment: @Fejs join will work on listof str so need to convert it back to string to concatenate

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed You're right, forgot this. Use `int("".join([str(x) for x in Array_number]))`.

Comment: dont complecate check my answer below... you too right but can do bit simple way

Answer (score 1):

Just a little hint without any code:

```
21135%10=5
21135-5:10%10=3
2113-3:10%10=1
211-1:10%10=1
21-1%10:10=2
```

Greetings